# Cómo establecer el Imagen.setImageResource desde un string

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este código y me gustaria saber como poder hacer lo que estoy intentando hacer

```
   public void SetImage(Cursor c){


    c.moveToNext();
    c.getString(12);

    im1.setImageResource( c.getString(12));      
}
```

lo explico: en una base de datos tengo una tabla que contine lo siguiente:

```
  string:"R.drawable.ic_launcher_background",
```

de esa base de datos saco un cursor con todos los campos de una tabla y todos sus datos. Pues bien, el c.getString(12) me saca dicho string y lo que quiero es poner esa foto en la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo más visible vamos a obtener la ruta en formato `string` dentro de un array.

```
String[] strRutas = {"R.drawable.image1","R.drawable.image2","R.drawable.image3","R.drawable.image4",
                "R.drawable.image5","R.drawable.image6","R.drawable.eliminar","R.drawable.image8"};
```

En mi caso voy a obtener esta ruta o `string` en cuestión `"R.drawable.eliminar"`.

```
String string = strRutas[6]; //"R.drawable.eliminar";
```

Ahora voy a trocear este String para obtener solo la palabra **`eliminar`**

```
String[] trozosStr = string.split("\\.");
String trozo3 = trozosStr[2];
```

Y ya con este porción de código completamos el resto. Decir también que hay que utilizar `setImageDrawable()` en vez de `setImageResource()`

```
        String uri = "@drawable/"+ trozo3;
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
        Drawable imagenDra = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), imageResource);
        imagen.setImageDrawable(imagenDra);
```

#### Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P.d. Por último decir que ya depende de la habilidad de cada uno para implementarlo en un método y que se haga más sencillo.